# How to generate a jsp page from an XML file

Tags: xml, jsp

My requirement is to generate a dynamic jsp GUI (a simple property form) using an XML file.The XML will have details like label,key,the component to be used (TextField/ComboBox etc).The value to be populated will be fetched from the database.Also the page generated should be modifiable by the user. In other words, I must be able to retrieve values from the page and send it to the server for further processing.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to develop a forms builder.

Not to put you off, let's get one thing straight. The more complex the requirements of the form's that are to be generated, the harder the implementation will be.

Will your forms span multiple pages? Will you have conditional fields? Validation?

If it's a simple one page form that just submits data. Then just iterate through the object that contains your form layout data, and render the form elements based on data in the XML.

You might want to consider XForms as your data structure:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/

Worth exporing the following before you commit to any work:

- http://www.orbeon.com/
- http://chiba.sourceforge.net/